# Выравнивание текста на кнопке

Tags: ios, swift

В моем коде цикл программно создает кнопки для view, при чем title состоит из двух частей:

```
btn.setTitle(name + String(value), for: .normal)
```

Каким образом можно задать **title**, чтобы **name** выравнивалась автоматически по левому краю, а **value** по правому? Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать это сделать выставив для каждого слова свои атрибуты. В примере приведена работа с словами на разных строках, но думаю адаптировать это для ваших нужд не составит труда:

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnTwoLine: UIButton?

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //applying the line break mode
    textResponseButton?.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping;
    let buttonText: NSString = "hello\nthere"

    //getting the range to separate the button title strings
    let newlineRange: NSRange = buttonText.range(of: "\n")

    //getting both substrings
    var substring1 = ""
    var substring2 = ""

    if(newlineRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        substring1 = buttonText.substring(to: newlineRange.location)
        substring2 = buttonText.substring(from: newlineRange.location)
    }

    //assigning diffrent fonts to both substrings
    let font1: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 17.0)!
    let attributes1 = [NSMutableAttributedString.Key.font: font1]
    let attrString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: substring1, attributes: attributes1)

    let font2: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 11.0)!
    let attributes2 = [NSMutableAttributedString.Key.font: font2]
    let attrString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: substring2, attributes: attributes2)

    //appending both attributed strings
    attrString1.append(attrString2)

    //assigning the resultant attributed strings to the button
    textResponseButton?.setAttributedTitle(attrString1, for: [])
}
```

[Вот первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679370/swift-uibutton-with-two-lines-of-text). Получается в вашем случае, нужно будет тоже разделить общий title на две составляющие и для каждой составляющей установить свое выравнивание. В первоисточнике использовались кнопки из сториборда, а вы будете использовать созданные вам кнопки программные, и для каждой кнопки будет сетить отредактированный текст. Так же можно попробовать создать свою кастомную кнопку, как это описано [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scTO8N6wc8A). Надеюсь смог вам помочь :)

Comment: `Получается в вашем случае, нужно будет тоже разделить общий title на две составляющие и для каждой составляющей установить свое выравнивание.` - применение разного выравнивания в строке без переноса не сработает

Comment: это единственное что пришло на ум)

Comment: тут только вариант с кастомной кнопкой остается

Comment: да единственный наверное) другим способом мне кажется такого добиться будет сложновато